# GWT layout to fill the entire screen area?

Tags: gwt

I'm developing a GWT application. I would like to know which of the layout/panel would occupy the entire screen area. For example, it should automatically fit in the screen size no matter whatever pixel the screen size may be (1280X1024 or 1280X960 or whatever). The application should automatically fill the screen. Please let me know which of the layout/panel would support this? Please suggest a link for a tutorial/page that could well explain this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using pure GWT, RootLayoutPanel is what you need.

Comment: Hi Maneesh,
 Could you please provide links for tutorial/examples??

Comment: Its always a good idea to refer to the API docs. Check out [link]http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootLayoutPanel.html[/link]

Comment: Ok. Looks like I messed up the formatting. Here is the correct link http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootLayoutPanel.html

Comment: Thanks. But its only Javadoc for the class. Can you please provide an example/tutorial to build application using GWT? Thanks...

Comment: Did you even bother to click on the link? Did you notice it already has an example working code. Sorry cannot spoon feed you more than this. Have a nice day.

Comment: Maneesh.. I checked the link and I have worked out my own examples.. I'm not asking you to spoonfeed.. Its just that I'm not clear with the concepts on layoutpanels. May be my replies doesn't have much of what I have been trying. I'm sorry for that. Ok, here is what I have been trying:

Comment: I created a rootlayoutpanel and then tried to split them into 3parts(with verticalpanels in them). with this, I'm getting an overlap of the logopanel and leftpanel. But, I want three panels to be aligned (I tried using Alignment.Stretch) centered with some space left at their sides(left,right,top,bottom). I asked the examples so that I could atleast find where I'm going wrong. Sorry for insisting on the word *examples*. Sorry again for not providing much info..

Comment: RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
  rp.setStyleName("gwt-RootLayoutPanel"); rp.setSize("100%", "100%");
  VerticalPanel logoPanel = new VerticalPanel();
  logoPanel.setStyleName("gwt-verticalpanel");  logoPanel.setSize("90%","15%");  
  rp.add(logoPanel); 
  VerticalPanel leftPanel = new VerticalPanel();
  leftPanel.setStyleName("gwt-verticalpanel"); leftPanel.setSize("90%", "70%");
  rp.add(leftPanel);
  VerticalPanel bottomPanel = new VerticalPanel();
  bottomPanel.setStyleName("gwt-verticalpanel"); bottomPanel.setSize("90%","10%");
  rp.add(bottomPanel);

Comment: rp.setWidgetTopHeight(logoPanel, 2, Unit.PCT, 15, Unit.PCT);
  rp.setWidgetLeftWidth(leftPanel, 10 , Unit.PCT, 80, Unit.PCT);
  rp.setWidgetVerticalPosition(leftPanel, Alignment.STRETCH);
  rp.setWidgetBottomHeight(bottomPanel, 2, Unit.PCT, 10, Unit.PCT);

Comment: Maneesh, I got it. It was as simple as that. I got confused with setwidgetLeftWidth() and setWidgetRightWidth() methods. I thought they are for the same widget.

Comment: I was playing around with other layoutpanels and found this quite abnormal that some panels doesn't actually fit in with respect to Style.Units.PCT which corresponds to CSS % unit. For example, even if I set the size of an element as 100%, 100% using setsize, it doesnt actually show up(fill the screen to 100%). I may be wrong as I'm not an expert as you are. Is this a limitation/drawback??